# Fined the order of the following subgroup of $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a positive integer $n\geq 4$ anfd a prime number $p\leq n,$ let $U_{p,n}$ denote the union of all p-sylow subgroups of the alternating group $A_n$ on $n$ letters. Also let $K_{p,n}$ denote the subgroup of $A_n$ generated by $U_{p,n}$ and let $|K_{p,n}|$ denotes the order of $K_{p,n}$. Then

(1)$|K_{2,4}|=12$

(2)$|K_{2,4}|=4$

(3)$|K_{2,5}|=60$

(4)$|K_{3,5}|=30$

I cannot get any idea how to do this problem. Please help me!

Comment: subspace should be subgroup?

Comment: sorry, it is subgroup. I edited

Comment: (1) and (2) seem to contradict each other.

Comment: May be you should first respond to the answers given to your other questions.. 8/12 of your questions are having no accepted answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The set $U_{p,n}$ is closed under conjugation, so the subgroup generated by their union is normal. At this point in your studies you should be able to list all the normal subgroups of both $A_4$ and $A_5$ and can check which one fits.